# AWS Aurora - adding error logs to Cloudwatch? (errorlog)

Tags: amazon-aurora, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I know you can export Aurora's audit logs to Cloudwatch, but I don't see any way to do that for the error logs/errorlog. That would enable us to set up a Cloudwatch alarm for failed scheduled events, etc. Am I just missing it?

It looks like they support it for MySQL RDS, but not Aurora.

I already have code that will query the error log files, but being able to set up an alert would make more sense (plus I wouldn't scan the logs every x minutes).

Comment: I agree with you.  I've not seen a way to export any of the other logs to Cloudwatch like you can on RDS MySQL based upon this doc: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html#USER_LogAccess.MySQLDB.PublishtoCloudWatchLogs)

Answer (score -1):

The AWS doc does not provide any info about this in the English page but it does in the French page.

Please see the link [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.CloudWatch.html).

Then you could translate thanks to Chrome.

1. Publication logs of Aurora MySQL in CloudWatch Logs with AWS management Consoles.
   You can publish logs of Aurora MySQL in CloudWatch Logs by the way of the console. To publish newspapers Aurora MySQL from the console :

   - Open the console Amazon RDS to the address https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/
   - In the shutter of navigation, choose **Clusters**.
   - Choose the cluster of database Aurora MySQL whose data of logs you want to publish.
   - For **Actions**, choose  **Modify the cluster**.
   - In the section **Exports of logs**, choose the logs which you want to begin to publish into CloudWatch Logs.
   - Choose **Continue**, then **Modify DB Cluster** on the recapitulative page.